# How can I make the page start from bottom to top for chat page in Flutterflow?

Tags: flutterflow

How can I make the page start from bottom to top for chat page in Flutterflow

I changed Main Axis Alignment to End
And it hasn't changed

I want the messages to appear on the chat page from the bottom, as is the case in other chat applications

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a list view make the list view property reversible to true and also use the expanded property so as your list view takes up the whole available space and starts it from bottom.